# what is a word for freebies given away at some events (e.g. orientation, job fair, ...)?

Tags: word-request

what is a word for freebies given away at some events (e.g. orientation, job fair, ...)? I remember there is a word whose form looks like "swag", but can't remember it.

Looks like swag is a right word, according to https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/887/ul-swag-for-top-users?
But by definition, a swag is obtained by stealing. How can it be a freebie given away?

Answer (score 5):

Words are often used figuratively or with extended meanings, especially in casual or slang contexts.  Calling such items "swag" means that it is as if they are stolen, because you got them for free.

Sometimes these extended sences get recorded in a dictionary.  Wiktionary has

3. (uncountable, informal) Handouts, freebies, or giveaways, often distributed at conventions; merchandise.

However if you don't want to make this connection, then calling them "freebies", is a good choice.

> I got some good freebies at the job fair, including this t-shirt.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/comp), the word **comp** can be used as a noun or a verb to t mean things provided free, or providing something for free. I guess that's an abbreviation for complimentary.

The term **swag** is used because often, at exhibitions or trade fairs, some people just cruise round helping themselves to (sometimes excessive quantities of) freebies, and stand holders suspect that such people only go for the freebies.